# Django raw sql query

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a this model:

```
class Document(models.Model): 
    data = models.TextField() 
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

How would you convert the following query for the model above to raw sql?

```
Document.objects.annotate(num_users=Count(users))
```

I need to switch this to raw sql because there is a bug in django when using MySql that makes annotate very slow.

But I'm not sure how to handle the many to many field in raw sql..

```
Document.objects.raw('SELECT ...')
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to translate your Django query to SQL is to simply look at the SQL that Django generates: [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Comment: Be careful! Maybe the bug he is talking about is how django translate that query to mysql syntax (although i hardly believe this query is treated differently in different DBMSs like postgre or mysql). If @9-bits feels that the raw query continues working slowly, he should add here the raw sql that django throws...

Answer (score 0):

*you can get corresponding query  the way mentioned below:*

```
queryset = Document.objects.annotate(num_users=Count(users))  
sql_query = queryset.query
print(sql_query)
```